# Script generates new Google spreadsheets from template and name them upon form-submitted data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to have this script working, but I'm missing something. It should grab data submitted via webform and stored in a spreadsheet that has this script attached, and then perform the following:

*create a new spreadsheet from a pre-formatted and ready-to-use template spreadsheet

*name the new spreadsheet with the data submitted via webform (eg. ID, date and else)

*also, the template as more than one sheet.

```
function CreateNewSS() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
ss.copy("Prefix " + data());  //create the new spreadsheet. 
var data = Range.getCell(0, 0); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserSubmittedData'); // sheet feed by web form 
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1); 
}
```

I'm stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of ss.copy

Comment: @ZigMandel: Thank you for noticing that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the onFormSubmit event to handle this. See [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) section of the documentation for details.

```
function onFormSubmit(e){

var resp = e.responses; 
var data = resp.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse().toString(); // Change 0 to the question number in the form
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
ss.copy("Prefix " + data());  //create the new spreadsheet. 

}
```

Comment: Hi Srik, Thanks for your recommendation, I will check the documentation to understand how the OnFormSubmit works.